# Dupe lookup and potential modification of user-submitted form data in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

My application has 3 primary object types:  Person, Home and Office.  Each of these objects have a Location (lat,lng and address) associated with it, and thus each of the tables (Person, Home and Office) include a location_id column, mapping to a Location in the Location table.

Person, Home and Office are each created with a simple form.  Within each of these object-creation forms (PersonForm.class.php, HomeForm.class.php and OfficeForm.class.php) I have embedded a LocationForm (LocationForm.class.php).

All is fine and well, users submit data (including location) about a person, home and/or an office, and data is properly saved in the db.

My issue is thus:  It is the case that more than one of my primary objects can each have/share the exact same location (lat, lng and address).  An Office and Home for example or perhaps a Person and Home could all share the same location.  That said, whenever objects are created a new Location is inserted into the Location table.

After user submission of the form, but ahead of saving it to the db, I'd like to query the Location table for a match (with Location being submitted), and if match then associate an already existing Location with this newly created Person, Home or Office object.

Much of what I've read points to overwriting an object's save() function, but if this is the case, and I'm overwriting the save() function within the Location model and I find a match, how then do I create the association with new object that is in the process of being created/saved (object being inserted should get location_id of the resulting location match) ?

Comment: You can write a `preSave` function for your Person/Home/Office form. If you find the `Location` object just insert it into the form so it won't get saved. You can also write a `preInsert` function for the `Location` object which will stop the save altogether if it finds the `Location` object.